# Unable to detach relationships on migrate:reset with Laravel / Eloquent ORM

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent, migrate

I've managed to get the Eloquent ORM, in Laravel, relationships up ok, but detaching them before dropping the related tables is proving to be very difficult and I don't think I'm doing it right as I get the following two errors as described below.

[image: errors returned after running "php artisan migrate:reset" command]

I've googled it to almost no end and most sources give a different method from each other, which isn't very helpful. Below is the current method I'm trying, which falls in line with documentation on the official Laravel site - http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships - I know the documentation only gives an example for detaching a single instance of one model, which is why I've put it inside a foreach loop.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableRelationships extends Migration {
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up() {
     Schema::table(
         'users', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('avatar')->references('id')->on('uploads')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
         }
     );

     Schema::table(
         'organisations', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('logo')->references('id')->on('uploads')->onUpdate('cascade');
         }
     );

     Schema::table(
         'groups', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('organisation')->references('id')->on('organisations')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('logo')->references('id')->on('uploads')->onUpdate('cascade');
         }
     );

     Schema::table(
        'uploads', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('uploaded_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
        }
     );
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down() {
     foreach(User::all as $thisUser) {
        $thisUser->avatar()->detach();
        $thisUser->save();
     }

     foreach(Organisation::all as $thisOrganisation) {
        $thisOrganisation->owner()->detach();
        $thisOrganisation->logo()->detach();
        $thisOrganisation->save();
     }

     foreach(Group::all as $thisGroup) {
        $thisGroup->organisation()->detach();
        $thisGroup->owner()->detach();
        $thisGroup->logo()->detach();
        $thisGroup->save();
     }

     foreach(Upload::all as $thisUpload) {
        $thisUpload->uploaded_by()->detach();
        $thisUpload->save();
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably not the problem, but it seems that you are only detaching the relation, but not actually dropping the table in your `down()`?

Comment: Is it that you just want to drop the table?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to remove them by manually deleting that migrations file, dump-autoload and drop the pivot tables from the database, before doing a migrate:refresh. Instead, I'm now creating the relationships via the model, using Eloquent's hasMany, hasOne, etc, etc, methods. Seems to be the safer and generally more widely accepted practice of creating schema relationships.